# How can I use a variable in a SqlDataSource SelectCommand?

Tags: .net, asp.net, mysql, vb.net

So making a .Net site with VB and running off of a MySQL server.

Trying to use a variable within the `connectionstring` to only retrieve certain data.

I Currently have in the header:

```
<script language="vbscript">
     Dim varSQLcommand as String

     varSQLcommand = "1"
</script>
```

and the connection string of

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:emergency systemsConnectionString3 %>" 
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:emergency systemsConnectionString3.ProviderName %>" 
    SelectCommand= "SELECT * from tbldisaster WHERE Disaster_ID = " & varSQLcommand & "" >
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Going to replace `varSQLcommand = "1"` with `varSQLcommand = Request.QueryString("ID")` and make the url `disasterdetails.aspx?ID={1}`.

is this the Correct way to do what I want to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SelectParameters` to set custom variables in your SQL:

```
SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM tblDisaster WHERE Disaster_ID = @Disaster_ID">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter QueryStringField="ID" Name="Disaster_ID" />
    </SelectParameters>
```

In this case, the filter criteria comes from the Query String (`?id=123`), so we use the `QueryStringParameter`, and bind it to parameter with name `@Disaster_ID`.  Then the query will pull the id value from the url and replace it where `@Disaster_ID` appears in the query.

Answer (score 0):

There is another question on here that may help you. You could either use the SelectParameters as stated in another reply, or you could declare them in your code-behind using the following:

```
Dim myDisasterID As String = Request.Querystring("id")
'Do whatever you may have to do with the variable

SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("variablename", myDisasterID);
SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM tbldisaster where disasterid=@variablename"
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485821/how-to-pass-variable-to-selectcommand-of-sqldatasource)