# Trying to pass dynamic values to a parameter in an SQL Data Source control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have some values that are being passed to a ASP.NET page using C# but I need those values to be set as parameters for an SQL datasource. I am just getting started with C# and ASP.NET so any help will be appreciated.

The data source code I have is as follows:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:PRS_atlantaConnectionString %>" 
                SelectCommand="SELECT [ExtNum] FROM [EXTINFORMATION] WHERE (([LastName] = @LastName) AND ([FirstName] = @FirstName))">
                    <SelectParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="DYNAMIC_VALUE_HERE" Name="LastName" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="DYNAMIC_VALUE_HERE" Name="FirstName" Type="String" />
                    </SelectParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Currently I am displaying the values on the page using the following code:

```
<%= FirstName %>
<%= LastName %>
```

Any help again will be appreciate it.

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/485821/how-to-pass-variable-to-selectcommand-of-sqldatasource

Comment: why you are using sqldatasource? using sqlcommands by code is more reliable

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the following to your code behind page:

```
   SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("LastName", yourdynamicstringvalue);
   SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("FirstName", yourdynamicstringvalue);
```

Or if you have something other than a string you are comparing with:

```
   SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("some_other_value",System.Data.DbType.sometype,"it's value as string here");
```

Once added, you'll need to remove the block below as it is no longer needed:

```
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="DYNAMIC_VALUE_HERE" Name="LastName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="DYNAMIC_VALUE_HERE" Name="FirstName" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
```