# Pass parameter id to sql query using url routing

Tags: asp.net, sql, c#-4.0

I'm a beginner asp.net developer

Trying to create my first simple news portal pages.

Here is what I have:

- Database
- Admin_News.aspx to add news into database
- Default.aspx to display all news with the title linkable
- NewsDetails.aspx to display the details by ID when they click on the title in Default.aspx

How I did That:

in Default.aspx I used this code:

```
<div>
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>title</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <b>news</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <b>imges</b>
                    </td>

                </tr>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="hl" NavigateUrl='<%#"~/NewsDetails.aspx?id=" + Eval("id")%>' Text='<%# Eval("title") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "news")%>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <img alt="" src='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "imageurl")%>' />
                </td>

            </tr>

        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            </table>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MoneyHolderConnectionString %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT [id], [title], [news], [imageurl], [detail] FROM [News]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
</div>
```

NewsDetails.aspx code:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MoneyHolderConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [title], [news], [imageurl], [detail] FROM [News] WHERE ([id] = @id)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="id" QueryStringField="id" Type="Int64" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>


    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2">
            <HeaderTemplate>

            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
               <h1 align="right"><br />
                 <strong><p style="color:#000">
                     <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "title")%>
                 </strong></h1><p/><br />
                 <br />

                 <p align="center"><img src='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "imageurl")%>'/>
                 <p/>
                 <br />
                 <br />

                 <p id="detail" align="right" style="font-size:25px"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "detail")%><p/>
                 <br />

            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>

            </FooterTemplate>
  </asp:Repeater>
```

so what I'm doing is displaying the article according to the ID in .aspx?id= in the url.
everything was working fine.. until I used the url routing.

I changed/added some codes to change the structure of the url I don't want it to appear like ~/NewsDetails.aspx?id=1 
I want to be like ~/News/1 instead with the same result.

So I have added this code to Global.asax:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    // Code that runs on application startup
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routeCollection)
{
    routeCollection.MapPageRoute("RouteForNews", "News/{id}", "~/NewsDetails.aspx");
}
```

and I added this code to the NewsDetails.aspx.cs code behind:

```
string id = Page.RouteData.Values["id"].ToString();
```

and I changed the NavigateUrl in NewsDetails.aspx to:

```
NavigateUrl='<%#"~/News/" + Eval("id")%>'
```

now when I open Default.aspx the news appear with the titles linkable to ~/News/"id number", when i click on a title, NewsDetails.aspx opens with the link of /News/idnumber but no data inside..its empty i only can see the design of the master page.

I would appreciate any help from you what should I do to display the news, the id value in the url it goes to string id variable but I don't know how to pass it to the sql query (i'm not sure if this is the problem)

Answer (score 1):

You should not use the `asp:QueryStringParameter` in the `asp:SqlDataSource` in the NewsDetails page, as your parameter is no longer in the QueryString. A QueryString is the part of URL that comes after the question mark.

Use this link to know how to pass parameters to select statement:

[How to pass variable to SelectCommand of SqlDataSource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485821/how-to-pass-variable-to-selectcommand-of-sqldatasource)

Comment: I have added this code in NewsDetails.aspx.cs behind code:

`SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("@id", id);`

and changed the selectparameter to this:

`<SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter  DefaultValue="<%= id %>" Name="id"  />
        </SelectParameters>`

i get this error when i run the page:

Server Error in '/' Application.
Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Comment: I removed the selectparameter code and added this code in .cs:

`SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters.Add("id", DbType.Int32, id);`

it worked ! thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

> connectionstring="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConnection %>"
>   selectcommand="SELECT Name, Age FROM ContactInfo where
>   State=@StateCode">