# Change the SqlDataSource SelectCommand

Tags: asp.net, gridview, sqldatasource

I have a `SqlDataSource` for a gridview. I want to change `SelectCommand` of that `SqlDataSource`.

My select command is:

```
select *   
from JobLog 
where UserName = @username 
  and PrinterName = @printer 
  and TimeSubmitted between @from and @to
```

I want to replace `@username` and ... with textboxes.

How can I do this?

Comment: **DON'T**! Instead: learn how to **supply proper values** for those parameters - **don't concatenate together your SQL commands!** - this opens all doors to SQL injection attacks - just don't even think about it. Learn the **proper way** - use **parametrized queries**

Comment: I want to do your way too. but I don't know how can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass variable to SelectCommand of SqlDataSource?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/485821/how-to-pass-variable-to-selectcommand-of-sqldatasource). The first answer of that question will show you how to do this properly with parameters.

Answer (score 1):

In your SQLDataSource, add SqlParameter to it.  Add one for each textbox that you want to use for the query.  Example:

```
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter Name="UserName" ControlID="txtUserName" />
</SelectParameters>
```

Comment: Please state that clearly in your question.  That will help you get the answers you are looking for.