# Pass variable to UpdateCommand of AccessDataDource in VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Trying to move code from aspx page to code behind. Can't seem to track down why I'm getting `Compiler Error Message: BC30451: Name 'UID' is not declared.` for `AccessDataSource1.UpdateParameters.Add("UID", DbType.Int32, UID)`

I need to move all but the GridView control. I have looked at [How to pass variable to SelectCommand of SqlDataSource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485821/how-to-pass-variable-to-selectcommand-of-sqldatasource) but doesn't solve error.

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Net.Mail

Partial Class _a_edit_students_revised1
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load  
    AccessDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT [UID], [StudentID], [UserName], [LastName], [FirstName], [HomePhone], [Affiliation], [Email], [Active],  [Career], [VolAdmin] FROM [UsersDataTbl] ORDER BY [LastName]" 
    AccessDataSource1.DeleteCommand = "DELETE FROM [UsersDataTbl] WHERE [UserName] = ?" 
    AccessDataSource1.UpdateCommand = "UPDATE UsersDataTbl SET UID = @UID, StudentID = @StudentID, LastName = @LastName, FirstName = @FirstName, HomePhone = @HomePhone,  Affiliation = @Affiliation, Email = @Email, Active = @Active, Career = @Career, VolAdmin = @VolAdmin WHERE UserName = @UserName"

    'AccessDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("userId", userId.ToString());

    AccessDataSource1.UpdateParameters.Add("UID", DbType.Int32, UID)
    AccessDataSource1.UpdateParameters.Add("StudentID", StudentID.ToString())
    AccessDataSource1.UpdateParameters.Add("LastName", LastName.ToString())
    AccessDataSource1.UpdateParameters.Add("FirstName", FirstName.ToString())
    AccessDataSource1.UpdateParameters.Add("HomePhone", HomePhone.ToString())
    AccessDataSource1.UpdateParameters.Add("Affiliation", Affiliation.ToString())
    AccessDataSource1.UpdateParameters.Add("Email", Email.ToString())
    AccessDataSource1.UpdateParameters.Add("Active", Active.ToString())
    AccessDataSource1.UpdateParameters.Add("Career", Career.ToString())
    AccessDataSource1.UpdateParameters.Add("VolAdmin", VolAdmin.ToString())
    AccessDataSource1.UpdateParameters.Add("UserName", UserName.ToString())

    'SqlDataSource1.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConString"].ConnectionString

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Well, where _is_ it declared? You've not shown us the code for _any_ of those declarations.

Comment: i thought those were declared somewhere in the asp.net side ? In the AccessDataSource1 control?