# Passing value from code behind to aspx file

Tags: asp.net, database, oledb

How do I get the value in my code behind. So, that I can use it on my aspx page?
I tried:

```
private int lastval;
public int LastVal { get { return lastval; } }
```

Then I will use it in gridview like this:`

```
 SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Order] where OrderId='<%=LastVal %>'"
```

But, it doesn't get the data.

Comment: Define "doesn't get the data". Errors? Wrong values? Something else?

Comment: it doesn't get the value of lastval in code behind that's why I can't use it for select statement of gridview in aspx page @SamiKuhmonen

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass variable to SelectCommand of SqlDataSource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485821/how-to-pass-variable-to-selectcommand-of-sqldatasource)

Comment: @SALOI posted a link for you to check. The problem is that Code Blocks (`<$= %>`) are executed too late in the pipeline, in the Page Render method, after your grid is bound.